# Google extensions.How to save button press time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to js. I need to save the time of pressing a button. Preferably in a txt file. How can I make it easier?

```
   const button = document.getElementById('logo')

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    console.log(now);},
    false)
```

Comment: You will need to use the [File System Module](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp) it will allow you to save content to a text file.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez This is just false. You can inject a download anchor instead if you're working on the client side (in fact, this is the better way to do it in client side code).

Comment: It is just a suggestion, feel free post you own, I'll even give it an UP vote if the answer is accepted

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const data = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(now.toString());
  const dlAnchor = document.createElement('a');
  dlAnchor.setAttribute('href', data);
  dlAnchor.setAttribute('download', 'button_time.txt');
  dlAnchor.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(dlAnchor);
  dlAnchor.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dlAnchor);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<p>Might not work here, but should work on your website.</p>
```